# vba how to immitate OOP style

Tags: vba, oop

I would like to have some hardcoded varaibles and I would like to separete this from my actual code. In PHP I would use a config class and call config->foo later on. Is that somehow similar possible in VBA?

I thought on a config function and call it like Config("Foo").

Does this somehow work or must I go via Global Variables for the solution?

```
Sub SomeFunction()

Dim I As Long

I = Config("Foo") ' is supposed to be I = 1

End Sub

Public Function Config(VariableName As String) As Variant

Static Foo As Long
Static Bar As String
Static SomeOtherVarThatIJustQuicklyMadeUp As String
Foo = 1
Bar = "Example"
Dim ReturnValue As Variant
ReturnValue = GetVariableByName(VariableName)
Config = ReturnValue

End Function
```

Comment: VBA supports creating and instantiating classes: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx  For `object(key)` you have the `Collection()` type or a `Dictionary()`.

Comment: Thank you! It seems like I always wanted to read this article.